# DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed

Tags: json, datatables

I am getting this error:

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'productsListTable'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.
```

Just want to make sure:

Does this: `table id = 'productsListTable'` means the problem is in the database's table named `prodectListTable`?

Comment: No, that likely much rather means that this error occurred when you tried to initialize datatables for your HTML element with the id `productsListTable` ... (how would a client-side plugin now anything about your server-side data structure to begin with - _especially_ if it can’t even understand the response the server gave to begin with.)

Comment: @CBroe Can I ask you for help? The live site is working, the offline copy I made which is currently sitting on `localhost` isn't working with the above error.

Why can it be? the code is the same in the live and the offline versions

Comment: Then start by checking how that request that is supposed to fetch the JSON data is answered, via your browser dev tools.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry for the lack of knowledge but how do I do it?

Comment: Nope, sorry - SO is not the place to explain the basics of debugging over and over again. Go find some beginner’s tutorials on that, if you don’t have the faintest idea yet how to go about that.

Answer (score 0):

No. Your `datatables` located on your front-end doesn't know about your database tables.

You have a `JSON formatting error` which is not a problem from the database but a `format` problem of the data you're trying to integrate to `datatables`.

Make sure you are a passing your data in the format that `datatables` is excepting to receive.